# Is there a word for someone who has a perfect life?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for someone who has a perfect life?

By perfect I meant someone who is happy in life with the things he has, who has balance, maybe someone having a loving wife, and doing his dream job or maybe, someone successfully balancing his studies, personal life as well as his work.

Comment: Hi Sanchita, can you please elaborate your question by giving some examples of what you consider as perfect life?

Comment: You might look at the classical concept of *eudaimonia*.

Comment: You've already used the word ***perfect***. What is it about that word that you find inadequate?

Answer (score 3):

You could say this hypothetical person lives a *charmed existence*. I've not heard someone described in the one word, *charmed*, but I suppose it could be used alone.

> Her life is perfect. She lives a charmed existence.

Or,

> His life is perfect. In short, he is charmed.

Comment: "Charmed life" is fairly common.

Comment: @HotLicks. Good point. Don

Answer (score 2):

He is **blessed**.

This word also has other (religious) meanings and connotations but you could use it here.

> characterized by happiness or good fortune.
>   *a blessed time*
>   -  [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blessed)

Answer (score 1):

In American English, a few words could work.  I think "charmed" as user rhetorician supplied above is my favored choice, but there are others.

Such a life could be [idyllic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idyllic) - pleasing or picturesque in natural simplicity.

In use:

> John Sinclair conducts the masterwork, which travels from the chaos at the dawn of time through Adam and Eve’s idyllic life in the Garden of Eden and beyond.

There's another option if you're wanting to describe the ideal as impractical or near impossible.  [Utopian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utopian) - of, relating to, or having the characteristics of a utopia; especially : having impossibly ideal conditions especially of social organization.

In use:

> A plan to revitalize the city's decaying downtown that proved to be overly ambitious and utopian.